# How i must use template hierarchy for CPT?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress CPT 
CPT name is -  cars
For this CPT i have Taxonomy -  carstype
In carstype  i create category's  type1  type2

Now i want that  type1  have it template and type 2 its

If i use single-cars.php  this will be same for both type1  and type2 , how make individually templates  for it 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

Use single-cars.php as single page template for cars. You can put check in single-cars.php

```
if( has_term( 1 ) ){
get_template_part(); //Template for type 1
}
elseif( has_term( 2 ) ){
get_template_part(); //Template for type 2
}
else{
get_template_part(); //Template for all other types
}
```

Comment: Instead type1 can i use  type1 id number ?

Comment: More details about term_exists() function here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_exists/

Comment: this code allays gives me,  get_template_part(); //Template for type 1 .  for type2 or type3.

Comment: I didn't get your point earlier, you need has_term() function, see updated answer.

Comment: has_term do same what is exist.  only showing first condition template

Comment: has_term() is specifically for current post. You can pass additional parameters as well like taxonomy name and post ID, check more on codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term